# Are type arguments passed along with an argument to a method?

Tags: java, generics, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

From my own experimenting I've concluded that any type arguments of an object or object reference is stripped when passed as an argument to a method. The question of type arguments pops up if a parameter of the method is parameterized with type parameters:

```
<T> void method (ArrayList<T> list) {
    list.add( (T) new Integer(4));
    sysout (list.get(0));
}
```

Then if we pass each of two parameterized ArrayLists to an invocation of this method:

```
method(new ArrayList<Integer>());
method(new ArrayList<String>());
```

We will see that neither produces an error and both print 4. I assume that the compiler retains the erasure of `T` as `Object`. Does this experiment not prove that type arguments aren't passed to a method?

Comment: `T` is unbounded, so what you really have is an `ArrayList<Object>`. That's why your code compiles.

Comment: The Java compiler just *checks* the generics at compile time. And then they get removed. Though the byte code running in the JVM has no idea what generic type you used. I guess that this may be because of compatibility, because before Java 5 there was only `List` (without generic types, because generics didn't exist back then), and when Java 5 was released it changed to `List<T>`, but you can still use `List` (without generics) event today and only receive some compiler warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of an `ArrayList<T>` is really the same case as a plain `T`. In both cases, `T` is used at compile time for the purposes of static type checking. However, at runtime, `T` is erased.

Looking at the code you posted, the compiled method is equivalent to this:

```java
void method (ArrayList<Object> list) {
    list.add( (Object) new Integer(4));
    sysout (list.get(0));
}
```

And the invocations are effectively:

```java
method(new ArrayList<Object>());
method(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

So from the runtime's perspective, you're storing `Object` in an `ArrayList<Object>`, which is fine.

Now, if memory serves, you should be getting a warning about an unchecked cast for the expression `(T) new Integer(4)`. That's a good warning to pay attention to! Casts usually throw an exception if the target type is not compatible with the actual type. In this case, though, `T` does not exist at runtime and therefore cannot be dynamically checked - the cast is a no-op. But, if we modify the example to return the casted value, you can start to see problems at runtime:

```java
<T> T method (ArrayList<T> list) {
    T value = (T) new Integer(4);
    list.add(value);
    return value;
}
```

And then

```java
String result = method(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Even though the cast succeeds (it's just a no-op), an exception will be thrown when the return value is assigned to `result` since the value is an `Integer` and not a `String`.

Comment: So then, in my example, would I be correct in saying that the type arguments of the parameterized objects I passed to the method are stripped and replaced with `Object`? You said that "the invocations are effectively: `new ArrayList<Object>`"

Comment: Essentially, yes. To be a little more precise, the objects themselves aren't parameterized - they don't exist until they are created at runtime, while `T` only exists at compile time. You could say the `T` is erased from the *expressions* prior to generating the byte code.

Comment: "the objects themselves aren't parameterized - they don't exist until they are created at runtime" What do you mean by this? Are you saying that sense parameterized types are non-reified that objects can't be parameterized as well? Consider these snippets: `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();` `list = new ArrayList<String>();` `list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` The last snippet causes an error. Does this not show that an object can be parameterized (at compile time)?

Comment: Since objects do not exist at compile-time (only at run-time), no it does not show that. Don't confuse _objects_ (run-time) with _expressions_ (compile-time). A `new` _expression_ gets compiled to _instructions_ which creates the _object_ at run-time. _Expressions_ (and other syntactic elements) can be parameterized, but _objects_ cannot be.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple case where the compiler isn't enabled to force you to use `T` within certain bounds. It's a bit as if your `method()` method doesn't care about `T` as a type, as you noticed.

The code is compiling, but with a warning. Your unchecked cast to `T` is not always without consequences:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
method(strings);
System.out.println(strings.get(0));
```

And:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

This exception is raised by `System.out.println(strings.get(3));`, because this call to `println` is linked to the overload taking a String, and the cast doesn't pass.

That means that although `method()` doesn't check the cast to `T` (at compile time or at runtime), the caller does. In my `main()` method, `T` is inferred as `String` and the runtime is able to perform the relevant type checks.

> I assume that the compiler retains the erasure of `T` as `Object`.

Roughly speaking, yes. But the compiler would be able to enforce more type safety in other cases, where `T` is bounded. The following won't even compile:

```
static <T extends String> void method(ArrayList<T> list) {
    list.add((T) new Integer(4));
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
}
```

So, "Does this experiment not prove that type arguments aren't passed to a method?" No. This is just one scenario of many.

Comment: So if the answer is no, can you provide an example where you pass a parameterized object to my example method that shows this? In your first example you use sysout after you pass it to the method, which is the reason for the produced error because in the sysout you are using a parameterized type that has type argument`strings` has type arguments (also because of the print stream like you said). In your second example you use a bounded type parameter. If the answer is no, then you must be saying type arguments are retained when an object is passed to a method. Please show example so I understan

Comment: I can also think of examples where I can do the same thing with a bounded type parameter. `Number` is the parent of both `Integer` and `Double` so I could assign values to a `Double` that aren't compatible with `Integer`

Comment: The way I understand "passed to a method" is "the concrete type argument is 'seen' and enforced in the method". If I misunderstand, please clarify. The type isn't "passed". The compiler just enforces it after doing type inferences.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. But, atleast in my example, the compiler seems to be enforcing the type erasure of `T` and not the type arguments of the two parameterized objects I passed to the method. Is it possible to get the compiler to enforce the type arguments of an object or object reference passed to a method or are the type arguments stripped and replaced with what the compiler infers?

Comment: Th other answer said that in my example the type arguments of the two objects I passed to the method become `Object` due to the erasure of `T`

Comment: @MatthewS. The compiler has ways of enforcing type safety there, but the developer can usually circumvent it (as in `Object o = "abc"; int i = (int) o;`, which easily fools the compiler). This is the same thing as in your example. Casting to unbounded `T` is useless, which is why the compiler doesn't validate it. If you want your example to be validated at compile time, you have to declare `T` as `<T extends Integer>` because that is what you expect it to be. This is the developer's work.

Comment: Sorry I think we are miscommunicating. You said that my experiment doesn't prove that the type arguments of a parameterized object or object reference (I guess identifier technically) when passed to a method aren't passed along with the object/reference. This means that you are saying that type arguments ARE passed along with the object/reference; but in order for this to be true, the compiler would enforce the type safety of the parameterized object/reference that's passed to the method, not the erasure of a parameter or the inference of type parameters.

Comment: @MatthewS. Using "passed" is a road to confusion. Types aren't passed, they are checked. And method signatures are convenient for the type checker - the body of the method and the callers can be checked independently for consistency with the signature. The type checker looks at the body of `method()` and says "Good! The body and signature are consistent." Elsewhere, it looks at a call to `method()` and says "Good! The call and signature are consistent". Since the call and body are both consistent with the signature, they must also be consistent with each other.

Comment: The only reason your example is confusing is because you **expressly** told the compiler to **not** check a certain part of your method body. That's what a cast is - you're saying "Hey type checker, I know you wouldn't normally allow this, but I'm telling you that I will always be able to assign an `Integer` to a `T`." And the the type checker says "Alright, if you say so!" If you do this with a concrete type, Java will add runtime checks to make sure things actually work out. But in your case, there is no type that could capture that check, so it does no checking at the point of the cast.

Comment: "Types aren't passed, they are checked" eureka! Good job explaining this simply